# Docker compose strange permission error issue

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, adonis.js

I am having this issue with docker that I cannot understand
I've created 3 micro services, all of them are adonis apps. All of thme uses the same `Dockerfile`. When I start them with `docker-coompose` only one of them does not want to work properly.

I get the following error:

```
EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/code/node_modules/.cache/adonis-require-ts
```

I don't understand why the other 2 micro services are running just fine, but this one throws this error

This is the `Dockerfile` of the micro service

```
FROM node:17-alpine

ENV ENV_SILENT=true

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

EXPOSE 3334

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

and this is what I have in `docker-compose.yml` for this service

```
services:
  notifications:
    build:
      context: ./../../../notifications
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3334:3334"
    volumes:
      - "./../../../notifications:/code"
    networks:
      - database
      - code
```

The other 2 micro services have the same `Dockerfile` the only thing that differs is the exposed port

Comment: the node modules that you are copying into the container may have owner as root. Instead copy the package.json and run npm install in docker file. Else try changing owner using this command RUN chown -R $USER /path/to/node_modules

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried both ways and I had the same result

Comment: The `volumes:` declaration you have completely hides everything the Dockerfile does.  I'd suggest deleting this block so that you're actually running the code you build into the image, or use Node instead of Docker if you want to run host code directly.  Don't forget to `RUN npm ci` in the Dockerfile so the image contains a `node_modules` tree.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @David Maze, I want to use docker because I have too many micro services and it's hard for me to start all of them. I use this setup as a dev environment, in production I for sure will use the code in the image :) I will try the `npm ci` command as well to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I think your Dockerfile should be like this:

```
FROM node:17-alpine

ENV ENV_SILENT=true

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci && npm cache clean --force

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3334

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

as you don't have `npm ci` (clean install) in your file

Comment: Can you elaborate on *how* and *why* this is expected to resolve the error described in the question?